# How to create sidebar menu with toggle button

Tags: c#, css, blazor, bootstrap-5, maui

I'm new to Blazor and I'm trying to create a sidebar menu with a toggle button.
I've tried to find references in the internet and I can't find any examples.
I'm trying to implement the following sidebar menu in Blazor using Bootstapper:
[https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-5-sidebar-menu-toggle-button-34132202](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

If someone can help me to implement this toggle, it would be very helpful. I just need a small example so I can implement it. The toggle is supposed to be exactly like the example. The sidebar needs to be minimized with icons.

Thanks!

I've tried to use the collapse example in the bootstrapper site.
I've tried to search everywhere to find examples and there are no examples in Blazor (for the exact sidebar menu).

Comment: No offense, but I think if you go through a couple Blazor tutorial videos, an especially the Blazor University homepage, you should be able to do this yourself.  "Please write some code for me" is unlikely to get much of an answer on SO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow does not exist to write code for you.

Comment: I honestly don't inderstand what the problem is. The link you gave *is* the example. It even includes the HTML, CSS, Javascript and resources needed to create the sidebar. Copy/Paste into an empty document was never this easy...

Comment: You may refer to [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988720/how-to-make-body-shifted-to-left-when-toggle-button-clicked-in-blazor) for help.